TON js client ERR_BAD_REQUEST when using testnet endpoint from ton center
I'm using @ton/ton js client to read data from TON blockchain using testnet endpoints from Ton center. I'm constructing the client like this:
 const client = new TonClient({
        endpoint: "https://testnet.toncenter.com/api/v2/jsonRPC",
    });

Every time I try to get data from the blockchain I get a weird error AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400 with code ERR_BAD_REQUEST, logging the following reason:
      '<html>\r\n' +
      '<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>\r\n' +
      '<body>\r\n' +
      '<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n' +
      '<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>\r\n' +
      '<hr><center>cloudflare</center>\r\n' +
      '</body>\r\n' +
      '</html>\r\n'

I have checked the error log and the endpoint is correct and is not http! The weird thing is that when I call the endpoint, using Postman, with the data provided in the error log, I get no error and the request is successful. Anybody experiencing the same problem?
